# Error PDO Exception SQLSTATE[42000] when using CakeDC Users plugin

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-model, cakedc

Iam using cakephp 2.2.1 and trying to use the cakedc users plugin, when I try to create a user I get the following error, can anyone give some tips or advice to resolve this error - I have loaded all tables using the migrations plugin. Thanks in advance :).

```
2013-04-07 06:31:33 Error: [PDOException] SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'register' at line 1
#0 C:\wamp\www\toppin\lib\Cake\Model\Datasource\DboSource.php(459): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 C:\wamp\www\toppin\lib\Cake\Model\Datasource\DboSource.php(425): DboSource->_execute('register', Array)
#2 C:\wamp\www\toppin\lib\Cake\Model\Datasource\DboSource.php(669): DboSource->execute('register', Array, Array)
#3 C:\wamp\www\toppin\lib\Cake\Model\Datasource\DboSource.php(611): DboSource->fetchAll('register', Array, Array)
#4 C:\wamp\www\toppin\lib\Cake\Model\Model.php(788): DboSource->query('register', Array, Object(User))
#5 C:\wamp\www\toppin\app\Plugin\Users\Controller\UsersController.php(331): Model->__call('register', Array)
#6 C:\wamp\www\toppin\app\Plugin\Users\Controller\UsersController.php(331): User->register(Array)
#7 [internal function]: UsersController->add()
#8 C:\wamp\www\toppin\lib\Cake\Controller\Controller.php(485): ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(Object(UsersController), Array)
#9 C:\wamp\www\toppin\lib\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php(186): Controller->invokeAction(Object(CakeRequest))
#10 C:\wamp\www\toppin\lib\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php(161): Dispatcher->_invoke(Object(UsersController), Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#11 C:\wamp\www\toppin\app\webroot\index.php(92): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#12 {main}
```

Add function:

```
public function add() {
        if ($this->Auth->user()) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__d('users', 'You are already registered and logged in!'));
            $this->redirect('/');
        }

        if (!empty($this->request->data)) {
            $user = $this->User->register($this->request->data);
            if ($user !== false) {
                $this->_sendVerificationEmail($this->User->data);
                $this->Session->setFlash(__d('users', 'Your account has been created. You should receive an e-mail shortly to authenticate your account. Once validated you will be able to login.'));
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'login'));
            } else {
                unset($this->request->data[$this->modelClass]['password']);
                unset($this->request->data[$this->modelClass]['temppassword']);
                $this->Session->setFlash(__d('users', 'Your account could not be created. Please, try again.'), 'default', array('class' => 'message warning'));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: and what do you have in add()

Comment: I have updated this post with add action from plugin's userscontroller

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, your `User` model is not being used by CakePHP or the `register()` method does not exist. CakePHP will execute non-existing methods as SQL statements. If a *Model* is not being used, CakePHP will automatically *create* a model, based on your `AppModel`

To discover if the `User` model was not found, try this;

```
public function add()
{
    debug(get_class($this->User));

    // ....
}
```

This should output `User`. If it outputs `AppModel` or `Model` then CakePHP is using a generic model, which indicates that it couldn't find your User-model.

- Clear your `app/tmp/cache/models` and `app/tmp/cache/persistent` directories, or if you're using APC, clear the user-cache.
- if you're using more than one Model in your controller, Check that the `User` model is in your `$uses` array
- Check that your User model is inside this file: `app/Model/User.php` and that the classname is `User` (singular, not *plural*)

If, on the other hand, your model *is* properly loaded (the debugging example shows `User`, not `AppModel`), then check if you actually have a `register()` method, if not, you should create if.

Hope this helps.

### [Update]

Just realised you're using the Users-plugin, and may be loading the *wrong* User-model. When using the plugin, you also need to use the `User` model from the **plugin**, not your own `User` model.

If you *do* have your own User-model, you should rename it to something other than `User` (e.g. `AppUser`) to prevent CakePHP from loading the wrong Model. Follow the instructions in the plugin-documentation on how to extend the plugins 'components' here: [extending the Model](https://github.com/CakeDC/users#extending-the-model)

However, if you want to extend the `User` model from the plugin, you'll also need to extend the `UsersController` of the plugin, see [Extending the Controller](https://github.com/CakeDC/users#extending-the-controller)

If you *dont* need to extend the plugin-Model and Controller, it's best to remove both from your application (e.g. `app/Model/User.php` and `app/Controller/UsersController.php`)

I've kept my original suggestions above, because they still may be helpful in other situations

Answer (score 0):

you should check the content in `$this->request->data` against the user table, maybe some value is not legal