# accessing CakeDCusers methods

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakedc

I'm using CakeDCusers but can't access that plugin's methods even when my other plugin Orders hasMany users.

```
$user = $this->Order->User->register($data);
```

gives me this:

Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'register' at line 1

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong? I know it's not much code, but let me know what if there's something more specific that you want.

Comment: found the answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15859720/error-pdo-exception-sqlstate42000-when-using-cakedc-users-plugin

Comment: How do you declare the hasMany declaration? There is your mistake. Also, why hasMany when an order usually belongsTo a user?